# Problem with using Pinia in a project -> export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { createPinia } from 'pinia';
import router from './router';
const app = createApp(App);
const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);
app.use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

when I try to use Pinia in my project it pops up an error that is in the subject line. I am using Vue 3, Laravel in my project.

I searched for a very long time for help, on the Internet and in GPT chat unfortunately nothing helped....I have a large project in Laravel + Vue, and I wanted to make a simple authentication in pinia, unfortunately any attempt to use Pinia in this project causes the same error.

Comment: are you sure the error is coming directly from main.js?  The error sounds like you're doing `import Vue from 'vue'` somewhere else... maybe your router index file (such code would be for a Vue 2 installation).  Otherwise, try removing the pinia related lines of code and see if the error persists.  Also, please post your package.json so we can verify all your dependencies are Vue 3 compatible.